# How can we align text fields from top to bottom in JFrame in java?

Tags: java, swing

How can we align Text Fields in java from top to bottom in JFrame? I want to align only one Text Field and it's Label in one line.The second TextField and it's Label may be placed under the first and so on.
Help me with example. I am a very beginner.

Comment: What you need is a GridLayout or GridBagLayout. There are many examples and tutorials on the interwebs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to place your GUI elements in a container. In your case a [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) or [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) would probably work best.

Comment: The `GridLayout` is the easiest to start with to learn the basics of using a layout manager. However is will be a bit artificial since it will force every component to the be same same. So try it to see how it looks. Then move on to the `GridBagLayout`. It will allow each component to be be its own preferred size, while still displaying in a row/column grid.

Comment: Good point, thanks for the tip. I'll edit my answer to include it.